# What is the difference between liquibase and Hibernate?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

How can I use both in same SpringBoot project? Will it not create conflict which one is going to create tables?

Answer (score 1):

[Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) is **Version Control System** dedicated for track, version, and deploy database schema changes.

Hibernate is **an object-relational mapping (ORM) tool** for the Java programming language which provides a framework for mapping an object-oriented domain model to a relational database.

Yes of course you can use both in same Spring Boot project. Check this official guide [liquibase + Hibernate](https://docs.liquibase.com/install/tutorials/hibernate.html) for Using Liquibase with Hibernate.